# How can i modify my image border"1" to have just one margin in html ?

Tags: html

I have created a border around my image;

I want to eliminate the right, left, and bottom stokes around the image but I do not know how to

Comment: just add `border-top:1px solid #ccc`....

Comment: Thank you so much. It works

Answer (score 0):

Refer [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp) for more info about borders

```
border-top: 1px solid red;
```